# Domain Driven Design, should I use multiple databases or a single source of truth

Tags: database, devops, domain-driven-design, business-logic

I'm about to propose some fundamental changes to my employers and would like the opinion of the community (opinion because I know that getting a solid answer to something like this is a bit far-fetched).

**Context:**

The platform I'm working on was built by a tech consultancy before I joined. While I was being onboarded they explained that they used DDD to build it, they have 2 domains, the client side and the admin side, each has its own database, its own GraphQl server, and its own back-end and front-end frameworks. The data between the tables is being synchronized through an http service that's triggered by the GraphQl server on row insertions, updates, and deletes.

**Problem:**

All of the data present on the client domain is found in the admin domain, there's no domain specific data there. Synchronization is a mess and is buggy. The team isn't large enough to manage all the resources and keep track of the different schemas.

**Proposal:**

Remove the client database and GraphQl servers, have a single source of truth database for all the current and potentially future applications. Rethink the schema, split the tables that need to be split, consolidate the ones that should be joined, and create new tables according to the actual current business flow.

Am I justified in my proposal, or was the tech consultancy doing the right thing and I'm sending us backwards?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you have a database, or schema, for each separated boundary context. That means, that the initial idea of the consultancy company was correct.

What's not correct is the way that the consistency between the two is managed. You don't do it on tables changes but with services inside one (or both) the domains listening to the events and taking the update actions. It's a lot of work, anyway, because you have to update the event handlers on every change (in the events or tables structure).
This code is what's called *anti corruption layer*, that's exactly what it does: it avoids any corruption between the copies of the domain in another domain.

Said this, as you pointed out, your team is small and it could be that maintaining such a layer (and hence code) could cost a lot of energies. But, you've also to remember that once you've done, you have just to update it when needed.
Anyway, back to the proposal, you could also take this route. What you should (must, I would say) is that in each domain the external tables should be accessed only by some services, or queries, and this code should never ever modify the content that it access. Never. But I suppose that you already know this.

Nothing is written in the stone, the rules should always be adapted when put in a real context. Two separated databases means more work, but also a much better separation of the domains. It could never happen that someone accidentally modifies the content of the tables of the other domain. On the other side, one database means less work, but also much more care about what the code does.